# Understand the tyre measurement of my CBF Stunner 2009 model

Tags: motorcycle, tires

`MRF - 2 Wheeler Tyres - Nylogrip ZRY - 130/90 R15 (66P)` What I can get out of this measurement is:

1. MRF - tyre manufacturer company
2. 2 Wheeler Tyres - type of vehicle tyre will get install to
3. Nylogrip ZRY - **what is this?**
4. 100/80 - **what is this?**
5. R15 (66P) - **what is this?**

**What if I use `90/90 tyre` instead of `100/80 tyre` for my CBF Stunner 2009 model 17" front RIM?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nylogrip ZRY is the model.

100/80 is the width in mm and 80 the height as a percentage of the width. Going to a 90/90 will change the arc profile and affect turn-in on the bike.

R15 means the wheel is 15 inches in diameter.

You should ensure you meet the manufacturers criteria for tyres as insurance companies have been known to cause issues if you fit an incorrect tyre.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good tyre size guide from [MobiTyre](http://mobityre.co.uk) on tyre size & the meanings of various numbers and letters

[image: MobiTyre Size Guide]

Comment: So how does changing the numbers affect the handling?